# pass data to controller on using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How to pass this below data to controller via ajax call

```
Stack Trace: at ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers.HomeController.ErrorBadRequest() in E:\Aprica\ApricaSVN\Project\Internal\Aprica\CRM_New\Integrated\ApricaCRMEvent\ApricaCRMEvent\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 46 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action f) at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

ajax call from view like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <center>
    <h2>Sorry, An Error Occured.</h2>
    </center>
    <% if (ViewBag.username == "admin")
       { %>

       <% if (Model.Exception != null ) { %>
            <p>
              Controller: <%= Model.ControllerName %>
            </p>
            <p>
              Action: <%= Model.ActionName %>
            </p>
            <p>
              Message: <%= Model.Exception.Message%>
            </p>
            <p>
              Stack Trace: <%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>
            </p>
        <% } %>

    <%}
       else
       { %>
        <center>
            <h3>Sorry for inconvinience caused. You can report this error to administrator.</h3>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="postError" value="Report Error" />
        </center>
    <%} %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#postError").click(function () {
                var vcontroller= "<%= Model.ControllerName %>";
                var vaction= "<%= Model.ActionName %>";
                var vmessage= "<%= Model.Exception.Message%>";
                var vstacktrace= "<%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Error/Error/',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        controller: vcontroller,
                        action: vaction,
                        message: vmessage,
                        stackTrace: vstacktrace    
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.result);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Some Error Occured while reporting Error.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

there occurs problem in code `var vstacktrace= "<%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>";`

```
at ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers.HomeController.ErrorBadRequest() in E:\Aprica\ApricaSVN\Project\Internal\Aprica\CRM_New\Integrated\ApricaCRMEvent\ApricaCRMEvent\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 46 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action f) at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

if anyone have idea please help....

Answer (score 0):

If this `#submit` is a submit button make sure that you cancel the default action by returning false from your callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Error/Error/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                sendEmail: true 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Some Error Occured while reporting Error.");
            }
        });

        return false;  // <!-- this is the important bit
    });
});
</script>
```

And now your controller action might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Error(bool sendEmail)
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously you can pass other information as well:

```
data: { 
    message: 'some message',
    sendEmail: true 
},
```

and the controller action could have this `message` argument as well.

Another issue with your code is that you have hardcoded the url to your controller action:

```
url: '/Error/Error/'
```

This is very bad because this way you are not taking advantage of your routing meaning that if you change the pattern of your route definitions in your Global.asax this url will no longer be valid. Also if you deploy on IIS in a virtual directory the correct url will now be '/YouAppName/Error/Error'. In order to take all this into account you should never hardcode the urls like this but use url helpers to generate them:

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("Error", "Error") %>'
```

Obviously this assumes that the javascript is inline inside your view and you can use the helper. If it is in a separate javascript file (which obviously is the correct approach) then you could use HTML5 data-* attributes in order to store the url as part of the DOM but yet be generated with a helper.

For example let's suppose that this `#submit` is some div in your DOM:

```
<div id="submit">
    Click me to submit
</div>
```

You could add a `data-url` attribute to it:

```
<div id="submit" data-url="<%= Url.Action("Error", "Error") %>">
    Click me to submit
</div>
```

and now in your separate js file you could use this attribute:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        ...
```

On the other hand if this `#submit` is a submit button of a form then simply use the `action` of the corresponding form. In this case do not subscribe to the .click event of the submit button but subscribe to the .submit event of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#your_form_id').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: { 
                sendEmail: true 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Some Error Occured while reporting Error.");
            }
        });

        return false;  // <!-- this is the important bit
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

In order to safely serialize some model property to a javascript variable you should use a JSON serializer:

```
var vstacktrace = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Exception.StackTrace) %>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your suggestions. Currently problem is the code is at `var vstacktrace= "<%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>";` line. its gives error and script doesn't rruns.

Comment: Does your model contain a property called `Exception`? Is this property assigned a value? Because if it is null it is obvious that you will get an exception if you attempt to call .StackTrace on it. I have updated my answer to illustrate how to properly serialize the model property to a javascript variable. Obviously this assumes that your model has this property and it is not null.

Comment: `<%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>` value is comming from `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>" %>`

Comment: Alright but did you verify that the `Exception` property is not null?

Comment: yes i verified. I think that the `<%= Model.Exception.StackTrace%>` returns a long value... having characters like `<>'/'`etc in it and thats why its getting java-script error. I have shown the value in question its returning.

Comment: And that's exactly why you should use a Json serializer as shown in my answer. Did you see my `UPDATE` at the end? Did you try it? What happened when you tried it?